# read more than 1000 txt files in core php

Tags: php, fopen

I have 1000 plus txt files with file name as usernames. Now i'm reading it by using loop. here is my code

```
for($i=0; $i<1240; $i++){                       
    $node=$users_array[$i];                     
    $read_file="Uploads/".$node."/".$node.".txt";                                
    if (file_exists($read_file)) {

        if(filesize($read_file) > 0){       
            $myfile = fopen($read_file, "r");                           
            $file_str =fread($myfile,filesize($read_file));                         
            fclose($myfile);  
        }
    }
}
```

when loop runs, it takes too much time and server gets timed out.

I don't know why it is taking that much time because files have not much data in it. read all text from a txt file should be fast. am i right?

Comment: Ok, so this code reads the files but does nothing with what it read? What else are you doing that may take up time??

Comment: define 'too long' in milliseconds, and also how many IOPS do you get from the file system where these files are stored ?

Comment: I’d replace the complete inner if with file_get_contents here first of all, instead of doing that whole does it have a size, if so, open it, read as many bytes as aforementioned size, and close it again-dance. If the size was zero, the result would simply be an empty string, so that could be used to decide if further processing is required.

Comment: the best bet is to split your file array into smaller chunks so you won't loose your potential data. or wait for experts opinion.

Comment: **It takes 0.23989295959473 seconds to run that code** _What Else Are You Doing????_

Comment: @RiggsFolly i parse it and then display but that is later part. if i skip the parsing just only try to read without doing nothing even then it takes too much time and never return.

Comment: To Much Time? How long is that????

Comment: And... How big are these files? And what do they contain?

Comment: @RiggsFolly can't analyze because server gets timed out.

Comment: @Tashen Jazbi How long is the code running until it starts to read these files? How long does it take to read one file? What's the maximum and average size of these files?

Comment: Ok, so if you run this script for lets say 10 files, how long does that take? AND do you get output??

Comment: @RiggsFolly dude, i commented all other code and just reading it. i skipped the rest of the code to check where it is taking time.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, it runs successfully even with 100 files.

Comment: Ok, so if you run it for 100, then 200, then 300 then ....... At what number of files does it hang?

Comment: Did you check the error logs to find out if maybe one of these files being corrupted has caused some sort of crash?

Comment: @RiggsFolly above 330 causing issue

Comment: How much time does it need to finish with 300 files?

Comment: Ok, so output the file name in the loop, then check that file for corruption and also the next one that the loop would have picked up

Comment: You can use microtime and file_put_contents to debug which part takes the longest and then tell us the result of the test. That way it would be easier to help you. I tiny improvement would be to change this: "Uploads/".$node."/".$node.".txt";  to this: "Uploads/$node/$node.txt";

Comment: @RiggsFolly now it is fixed, thanks for help. the code was right. now it is taking time at the time of parsing. I'm digging it why it is happening so there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are doing read operations on HDD/SSD which are not as fast as memory, so you should expect a high running time depending on how big the text files are. You can try the following:

- if you are running the script from browser, I recommend running it from command line, this way you will not get a web server time out and the script will manage to finish if there is no time execution limit set on php, case in which maybe you should increase it
- on your script above you can set "filesize($read_file)" into a variable so that you do not execute it twice, it might improve running the script
- if you still can't finish the job consider running it in batches of 100 or 500
- keep an eye on memory usage, maybe that is why the script dies
- if you need the content of the file as a string you can try "file_get_contents" and maybe skip "filesize" check all together

Comment: you are using it twice, once to check if size is higher than 0 and the second one when you read it

Comment: if you don't know why the script time outs, it might be the memory, because of how big the files are, out file names, see if it always stops at the same file, and also benchmark how fast your file reads go, and if so try eliminating the file that hinders your program from running, maybe some files are too big, case in which you should consider an async job in the background to do this task

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is having 1000+ files in a single directory. On a traditional Unix file system, finding a single file by name requires scanning through the directory entries one by one. If you have a list of files and try to read all of them, it'll require traversing about 500000 directory entries, and it will be slow. It's an O(n^2) algorithm and it'll only get worse as you add files.

Newer file systems have options to enable more efficient directory access (for example https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories) but if you can't/don't want to change file system options you'll have to split your files into directories.

For example, you could take the first two letters of the user name and use that as the directory. That's not great because you'll get an uneven distribution, it would be better to use a hash, but then it'll be difficult to find entries by hand.

Alternatively you could iterate the directory entries (with opendir and readdir) and check if the file names match your users, and leave dealing with the problems the huge directory creates for later.

Alternatively, look into using a database for your storage layer.